# From Automorphism to abelian ness ... in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group such that for any two non-identity elements $a,b$ in $G$ , there is an Automorphism of $G$ sending $a$ to $b$ , then is it true that $G$ is abelian ?

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with the result already, but the result is false without the finiteness assumption. There's even an infinite group (constructed via HNN-extensions) in which any two non-identity elements are conjugate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Suppose $G\neq 1$.  Since there exists an element with prime order, and all non-identity elements of $G$ have the same order, $G$ is a $p$-group.  Therefore $Z(G)\neq 1$.  But automorphisms preserve the center, so $Z(G)=G$.